# ActionListener when clicking row in JTable. How?

Tags: java, swing, linked-list, jtable, actionlistener

I am currently creating the GUI for my school project. It is a theatre management program that lets you add Groups. To these groups you can then add Students and Rehearsal dates. All of this is stored in separate LinkedLists. 
Now, I have a Tab in my program with a JTable that contains all the Groups. 
What I want, is the following: When the user clicks on one of the records in the JTable, a new JDialog pops up that displays two JTables, one that displays all the students in that group, and one that displays all the rehearsals assigned to that group. 
How can this be done?

I am not requesting full code (would be nice though), just want to know how I can make the records clickable, so that I can then add an ActionListener to the event of clicking on one of the records.

I hope that makes sense :/

If you need any code from my program, tell me. I just don't know what you would possibly need.

Comment: Take a look at this SO question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378096/actionlistener-on-jlabel-or-jtable-cell

Comment: I look at a `ListSelectionListener` instead of a `MouseAdapter`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14801908/230513).